# C convert decimal number to binary using union

Tags: c, binary, unions

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    long long int n,b,t,j;
    while(scanf("%llu",&n) && n)
    {
        char a[2000]={0},c[2000]={0};
        b=0;
        int k=0;

        while(n>0)
        {
            a[b++]=(n%2)+48;
            if(n%2==1)
            k++;
            n=n/2;
        }
            a[b]='\0';
            j=strlen(a)-1;

        for(b=j,t=0;b>=0;b--)

            c[t++]=a[b];
            c[t]='\0';

        printf("The parity of %s is %d (mod 2).\n",c,k);
    }

return 0;
}
```

This code working perfect.

Now I want to convert decimal number to binary using union in C

How can I do that?

Comment: The number `n`, once interpreted *from* decimal text representation, is *not* "decimal". It's just a number, typically stored as binary in your computer's memory.

Comment: `a[b++]=(n%2)+48;`. no cast? is this possible?

Comment: @Koushik What cast? Why would one be needed?

Comment: @H2CO3 a[] is a char array, n is a long long int.

Comment: @H2CO3 is it safe without explicit cast?i mean he is obtaining the remainder yes but isnt the expression dealing with a long long int?

Comment: i believe you are asking about representing the number into binary...dont use word convert....is it so?

Comment: @Koushik Only values matter. If the result is greater than what is representable by a `char`, then it will be truncated (or if `char` is signed, overflow and cause undefined behavior). And this will be the case whether or not you cast it.

Comment: @H2CO3 i do agree that the behavior is undefined even with cast. but i had in mind that the complier would ignore if there was explicit cast and complain otherwise.

Comment: @Koushik 1. it won't, 2. if it did, then that would be another reason **not** to include the cast, since you would then get a false negative (i. e. a hidden error).

Comment: @H2CO3 ah! learnt.:-)

Comment: @Koushik Cool :) Typically, if you're casting to silence a compiler error, then you're doing something wrong (not always, but it's a pattern).

Answer (score 3):

You can't, that doesn't make any sense. Decimal and binary are *representations* of numbers. Ten cars in decimal is the same number of cars as ten cars in binary. It's precisely the same number. There's no way to use a union to change one integer representation to another.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number is not represented in decimal in memory, you have already accomplished this task, without even using a union. If you want to obtain a binary **textual** representation:

```
unsigned n = 12345;

for (int i = sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    putc('0' + ((n >> i) & 1), stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why?

A union is merely a structure where all the members have the same location in memory (they overlap).

I'm not familiar with any typical approach for using a union when creating a binary string, I don't think that's (easily) possible at all.

Perhaps you're confusing the use of unions when converting between floating point and integers (ugly but sometimes used to get at the bits for a floating point number)?

Comment: I have to do on the basis of union, because the teacher requires it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
union calc
{
    struct {
        unsigned char bit0  : 1;
        unsigned char bit1  : 1;
        unsigned char bit2  : 1;
        unsigned char bit3  : 1;
        unsigned char bit4  : 1;
        unsigned char bit5  : 1;
        unsigned char bit6  : 1;
        unsigned char bit7  : 1;
    } bits;
   unsigned char numero;
};  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    union calc  c;
    scanf("%u",&c.numero);
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",c.bits.bit7,c.bits.bit6,c.bits.bit5,c.bits.bit4,c.bits.bit3,c.bits.bit2,c.bits.bit1,c.bits.bit0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Care to elaborate on what you fixed?